# Array into dataframe interpolation

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following array:

```
[299.13953679 241.1902389  192.58645951 ...   8.53750551  24.38822528
  71.61117789]
```

For each value in the array I want to get the interpolated `wind speed` based on the values in the column `power` in the following `pd.DataFrame`:

```
    wind speed  power
5          2.5      0
6          3.0     25
7          3.5     82
8          4.0    154
9          4.5    244
10         5.0    354
11         5.5    486
12         6.0    643
13         6.5    827
14         7.0   1038
15         7.5   1272
16         8.0   1525
17         8.5   1794
18         9.0   2037
19         9.5   2211
20        10.0   2362
21        10.5   2386
22        11.0   2400
```

So basically I'd like to retreive the following array:

`[4.7 4.5 4.3 ... 2.6 3.0 3.4]`

Any suggestions on where to start? I was looking at the `pd.DataFrame.interpolate` function but reading through its functionalities it does not seem to be helpful in my problem. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `interp` from `numpy`

```
np.interp(ary,df['power'].values,df['wind speed'].values)
Out[202]: 
array([4.75063426, 4.48439022, 4.21436922, 2.67075011, 2.98776451,
       3.40886998])
```